# Бейджи в Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, material-design

Как реализовать бейджи в `Navigation Drawer menu`?

[Пример бейджев: 10 и 99+ (картинка)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Q29n.png)

В бейджи хочу выводить количественные данные из БД.Создал разметку:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:layout_weight="85" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:drawablePadding="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@color/myTextPrimaryColor" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:layout_weight="15" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Так добавляю новые элементы в список. файл: `NavigationDrawerFregment`

```
public List<NavigationItem> getMenu() {
    List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
    String[] nav_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.views_array);
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[0], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[1], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[2], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[3], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_tooth)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[4], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_tooth_doc)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[5], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    return items;
}
```

В итоге имею обновленную разметку, но не знаю как выводить в нужный элемент меню.

Код `NavigationItem`:

```
public class NavigationItem {
private String mText;
private Drawable mDrawable;

public NavigationItem(String text, Drawable drawable) {
    mText = text;
    mDrawable = drawable;
}

public String getText() {
    return mText;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    mText = text;
}

public Drawable getDrawable() {
    return mDrawable;
}

public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mDrawable = drawable;
}
```

}

**UPD2**
- my NavigationDrawerAdapter

```
public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<NavigationItem> mData;
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
private View mSelectedView;
private int mSelectedPosition;
private TextView badge_tv;

public NavigationDrawerAdapter(List<NavigationItem> data) {
    mData = data;
}

public NavigationDrawerCallbacks getNavigationDrawerCallbacks() {
    return mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
}

public void setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(NavigationDrawerCallbacks navigationDrawerCallbacks) {
    mNavigationDrawerCallbacks = navigationDrawerCallbacks;
}

@Override
public NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_row, viewGroup, false);
    final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    viewHolder.itemView.setClickable(true);
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void onClick(View v) {
                                                   if (mSelectedView != null) {
                                                       mSelectedView.setSelected(false);
                                                   }
                                                   mSelectedPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
                                                   v.setSelected(true);
                                                   mSelectedView = v;
                                                   if (mNavigationDrawerCallbacks != null)
                                                       mNavigationDrawerCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition());
                                               }
                                           }
    );
    viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.row_selector);
    badge_tv = (TextView) viewHolder.itemView.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
    viewHolder.textView.setText(mData.get(i).getText());
    viewHolder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mData.get(i).getDrawable(), null, null, null);
    if (mSelectedPosition == i) {
        if (mSelectedView != null) {
            mSelectedView.setSelected(false);
        }
        mSelectedPosition = i;
        mSelectedView = viewHolder.itemView;
        mSelectedView.setSelected(true);
    }

    if (mData.get(i).getBadge().equals("")) badge_tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    else { badge_tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        badge_tv.setText(mData.get(i).getBadge());
    }
}


public void setBadge(int count , int pos){
    mData.get(pos).setBadge(String.valueOf(count)) ;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void dropBage(int pos){ // убрать бэйдж из пункта pos
    mData.get(pos).setBadge("");
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}


public void selectPosition(int position) {
    mSelectedPosition = position;
    notifyItemChanged(position);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    }
}
```

**UPD3**
- NavigationDrawerFragment

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

/**
 * Remember the position of the selected item.
 */
private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";

/**
 * Per the design guidelines, you should show the drawer on launch until the user manually
 * expands it. This shared preference tracks this.
 */
private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";

/**
 * A pointer to the current callbacks instance (the Activity).
 */
private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;

/**
 * Helper component that ties the action bar to the navigation drawer.
 */
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;

private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
private View mFragmentContainerView;

private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;

String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Read in the flag indicating whether or not the user has demonstrated awareness of the
    // drawer. See PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER for details.
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
    mUserLearnedDrawer = sp.getBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, false);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
        mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
    mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();
    NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationItems);
    adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
    selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    return view;
}

public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
    return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
}

public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
    return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
}

public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
    return mDrawerLayout;
}

@Override
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    selectItem(position);
}

public List<NavigationItem> getMenu() {
    List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
    String[] nav_items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.views_array);
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[0], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[1], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[2], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[3], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[4], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    items.add(new NavigationItem(nav_items[5], getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_check)));
    return items;
}

/**
 * Users of this fragment must call this method to set up the navigation drawer interactions.
 *
 * @param fragmentId   The android:id of this fragment in its activity's layout.
 * @param drawerLayout The DrawerLayout containing this fragment's UI.
 * @param toolbar      The Toolbar of the activity.
 */
public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    mDrawerLayout.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.myPrimaryDarkColor));

    mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) return;
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) return;
            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
            Log.v(LOG_TAG, "dr opened");
            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.
    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
    if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    if (mCallbacks != null) {
        mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
    }
    ((NavigationDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
}

public void openDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}

public void closeDrawer() {
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mCallbacks = null;
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Forward the new configuration the drawer toggle component.
    mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

public void setUserData(String user, String email, Bitmap avatar) {
    ImageView avatarContainer = (ImageView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
    ((TextView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUserEmail)).setText(email);
    ((TextView) mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.txtUsername)).setText(user);
    avatarContainer.setImageDrawable(new RoundImage(avatar));
}

public View getGoogleDrawer() {
    return mFragmentContainerView.findViewById(R.id.googleDrawer);
}

public static class RoundImage extends Drawable {
    private final Bitmap mBitmap;
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final RectF mRectF;
    private final int mBitmapWidth;
    private final int mBitmapHeight;

    public RoundImage(Bitmap bitmap) {
        mBitmap = bitmap;
        mRectF = new RectF();
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        final BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(bitmap, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
        mPaint.setShader(shader);

        mBitmapWidth = mBitmap.getWidth();
        mBitmapHeight = mBitmap.getHeight();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawOval(mRectF, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds);
        mRectF.set(bounds);
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
        if (mPaint.getAlpha() != alpha) {
            mPaint.setAlpha(alpha);
            invalidateSelf();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
        mPaint.setColorFilter(cf);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
        return mBitmapWidth;
    }

    @Override
    public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
        return mBitmapHeight;
    }

    public void setAntiAlias(boolean aa) {
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(aa);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) {
        mPaint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    @Override
    public void setDither(boolean dither) {
        mPaint.setDither(dither);
        invalidateSelf();
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap() {
        return mBitmap;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Вам в библиотеке NeoKree надо или вы решили самостоятельно реализовать подобный функционал? Если да, то не тратьте время впустую, придумывая то, что уже есть и отлично работает. [Mike Penz - MaterialDrawer](https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer) или библиотека того же NeoKree с скриншота, но она несколько проигрывает первой.

Comment: @pavlofff, могу я самостоятельно урезать библиотеку Майка Пенза ? 
Я встречал ее, она имеет богатый функционал, но мне нужна лишь ее часть.

Comment: Исходники есть - значит можете, но это не очень этично будет

Comment: @pavlofff, я не хочу присвоить себе его код. Мне не нужен весь функционал либы Майка. Поэтому и спросил про урезанную версию. 
На данный момент использую шаблон Navigation Drawer, который обновлен до Material Design и импортирован в Android Studio. Но он не имеет бейджей, а они мне нужны.

По сути если, то я уже почти реализовал себе бейджи (изменил разметку и оформил как нужно, есть информация для вывода, но не знаю куда мне ее прописать в коде, что отобразить именно в тот textView, что мне нужен.

Comment: @pavlofff, обновил вопрос - немного добавил кода.

Comment: В общем то я не вижу проблемы в избыточной функциональности библиотек - `proguard` может удалить неиспользуемые классы из релизной сборки.

Comment: Не вижу смысла урезать функционал, не нужно что то, не используйте, а то после выпиливания получите потом непонятные баги

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализация этих бэйджев может быть разными способами - предлагаю наиболее компромиссный и полнофункциональный, то есть бэйджи могут быть не у всех пунктов и тогда значок бэйджа не появляется вовсе.

Так как генерация айтемов при прокрутке происходит по запутанным законам, сохранять значения для бэйджев нам необходимо в каком то отдельном хранилище, чтобы при пересоздании айтема  оно не было утрачено. Хранить эти значения будем в списке моделей с вашими пунктами.

В класс-холдер добавим ссылку на новый элемент `badgeView`:

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        public TextView badgeView;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            badgeView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.badge);
        }
    }
```

В методе `onBindViewHolder()` адаптера проверяем, есть ли значение для бэйджа и устанавливаем видимость\невидимость виджета, который его отображает:

```
@Override 
public void onBindViewHolder(NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    if (mData.get(i).getBadge().equals("")) viewHolder.badgeView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
     else { viewHolder.badgeView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            viewHolder.badgeView.setText(mData.get(i).getBadge());
     }
```

В адаптере реализуем сеттер, для установки значений в бэйдж (если понадобится гeттeр его вы тоже можете организовать естественно):

```
public void setBadge(int count , int pos){
      mData.get(pos).setBadge(String.valueOf(count)) ;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void dropBadge(int pos){ // убрать бэйдж из пункта pos
      mData.get(pos).setBadge("")) ;
      notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

В модель добавляем поле для сохранения значений бэйджа (при желании вы можете добавить инициализацию начального значения бэйджа в конструктор и задавать его при заполнении пунктов списка, если это требуется):

```
public class NavigationItem {
private String mText;
private Drawable mDrawable;
private String mBadge;

public NavigationItem(String text, Drawable drawable) {
    mText = text;
    mDrawable = drawable;
    mBadge = "";
}

public String getText() {
    return mText;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    mText = text;
}

public Drawable getDrawable() {
    return mDrawable;
}


public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
    mDrawable = drawable;
}

public String getBadge() {
    return mBadge;
}

public void setBadge(String badge) {
    mBadge = badge;
}
}
```

Пользоваться этим добром предлагается так - в активити\фрагменте устанавливаете значение для бэйджа через экземпляр адаптера,который подключаете к `ReciclerView()` с пунктами списка, значение `pos` вам нужно выбрать самостоятельно, исходя из позиции того пункта в котором необходимо показать бэйдж (здесь - в третий пункт драйвера вывести значение 15):

```
navigationDrawerAdapter.setBadge( 15, 2);
```

Если вам требуется писать всякие `+99` и не выводить отрицательные значения - реализуйте в сеттере дополнительную функциональность по преобразованию числа `count` в строку для виджета с нужным форматированием.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24126/discussion-between-web-alex-and-pavlofff).

Answer (score 4):

Нужно создать метод в вашем класе меню, например:

```
 public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 public TextView item_name_tv, badge_tv, notifications;
 private int notificationsNumber;

 public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
 super(itemView);
    item_name_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
    badge_tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.badge);
    notifications = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.notification_id);
    notificationsNumber = 0;
 }

 public ViewHolder setNotifications(int notifications) {
    String textNotification;

    textNotification = String.valueOf(notifications);

    if(notifications < 1) {
        textNotification = "";
    }
    if(notifications > 99) {
        textNotification = "99+";
    }

    this.notifications.setText(textNotification);
    numberNotifications = notifications;

    return this;
}
}
```

В layout добавить еще один TextView:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="start"
android:layout_weight="85" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:drawablePadding="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textColor="@color/myTextPrimaryColor" />
 <TextView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/notification_id"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:lines="1"
    android:maxLength="3"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: notifications я заменю на свое count, т.к. нужно выводить количество записей в таблице БД. А как мне выводить конкретно в определенный элемент (бейдж) ? никак не могу передать int в метод setNotifications.

Comment: какой код вашего NavigationItem?

Comment: обновил вопрос - UPD1.