# Принцип создания иконки приложения с счетчиком android?

Tags: android, android-button

У меня уже много вопросов которые связаны одним проектом, и вот сейчас у меня возникла идея создать иконку со счетчиком непрочитанных (новых) сообщений, так как я работаю с сообщениями. У меня есть приблизительное представление как сделать иконку со счетчиком новых входящих сообщений, но после прочтения моего виденья этого вопроса вы поймете, что оно имеет слабые места (пока не знаю какие).

Как я себе это вижу - с сервера приходит вместе со списком сообщений такая переменная как `count` которая равна количеству сообщений, в зависимости от того сколько сообщений на момент запроса тому и равна переменная. Я думаю что при каждом запросе списка входящих сообщений нужно эту переменную сохранять.

Дальше я так думаю что у приложения должен быть какой-то фоновый процесс который будет висеть в фоне, при наличии интернета, посылать запрос на получения списка входящих сообщений, и тоже с этого запроса будет тянуться количество входящих сообщений. И дальше эти две сохраненные переменные будут выниматься из настроек и их разница будет отображаться в иконке.

То есть будет отдельный процесс который будет висеть в фоне и будет четко направлен на получение количества сообщений.

Но вот например представим что я каким-то магическим образом смог получить разницу в количестве сообщений, и теперь у меня есть разница которая сохранена в переменной. Дальше следующим шагом будет наверное создание кастомной иконки, где будет поле куда будем писать нашу разницу в сообщениях. Для этого нужно будет создать новый файлик `xml` где будет макет нашей иконки. И если все сделано правильно то у нас на выходе будет рабочая иконка.

Но есть один нюанс - вероятнее всего нужно будет как-то реализовать обнуление счетчика, я так думаю что когда юзер увидит новое сообщение, то он соответственно откроет приложение, и при запуске приложения тоже будет посылаться запрос на получение списка сообщений, и если я правильно понимаю то счетчик слетит на 0.

Все вышесказанное - это только **мое личное** виденье стратегии разработки и создания иконки-счетчика, и **вероятнее всего мое стратегия** не совсем верна, или вообще **ошибочна**. Возможно на **StackOwerflow** есть инструкция которая ответит на все мои вопросы, но я ее не нашел.

Если кто-то уже исследовал вопрос по созданию такой иконки, то буду очень рад если поделитесь результатами ваших стараний и опытом в этом вопросе. Заранее благодарен за помощь.

Comment: ок я понял, сейчас исправлю, буду рад если вы просмотрите обновленную версию для предотвращения подобных сложностей.

Comment: есть [готовые либы](https://github.com/search?q=badge). Если вам интересно сделать самому, можете посмотреть их исходный код. Еще я [вот тут писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/425795/Бейджи-в-navigation-drawer) о подобном.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за информацию, только я единственное что никак не могу понять  - это как получить доступ к иконке в лаунчере, я видел туториалы как сделать кнопку с счетчиком, но вот как поменять иконку я к сожалению не нашел.

Comment: счетчик в иконке лаунчера не поддерживается API android. данная функция доступна лишь на некоторых кастомных лаунчерах (например от самсунг) и ее наличие будет зависеть от того, какой лаунчер установлен у пользователя и вы из кода не можете повлиять на появление такого счетчика на любом устройстве. Тоже [есть библиотеки](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger) для данной функции