# Уведомления на значках андроид

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Уведомления на значках программы, как они работают и как это можно реализовать?

[image: Вот такие уведомления]

Есть ли возможность реализовать такие значки в программе типа интернет магазина,где  реализуется вот такой метод :

`MenuDetail2API = Constant2.MenuDetail2API+"? 
     accesskey="+Constant2.AccessKey+"&menu_id="+Menu_ID;`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/871984/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-android